# Key, KeyRef in different XSD documents

Tags: xml, xsd

Is this possible?

Say for example I have

customers.xml

```
<customers>
    <customer>1</customer>
    <customer>2</customer>
</customers>
```

orders.xml

```
<orders>
    <order>
        <customer>1</customer>
    </order>
    <order>
        <customer>3</customer> Invalid as Customer 3 doesn't exist
    </order>
</orders>
```

How would the XSD (using key and keyref) look for this (customer.xsd and orders.xsd would also be two different files with different namespaces), is it even possible. All the examples I have seen deal with single files.

[Can Keys and Keyrefs be spread across multiple XSD files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101120/can-keys-and-keyrefs-be-spread-across-multiple-xsd-files)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. No XML schema construct or constraint works across multiple files.