# How to define xml primary key in xsd file and validate in xml file

Tags: xml, xsd

Buildings.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="buildings">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>

<xs:element name="building" maxOccurs="unbounded">

  <xs:complexType>

    <xs:sequence>

      <xs:element name="BuildingCode">
        <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{3}"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>

      <xs:element name="BuildingName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Position" type="Position"/>
     <xs:element name="Address" type="Address" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:key name="PKBuildingCode">
            <xs:selector xpath="building"/>
            <xs:field xpath="BuildingCode"/>
        </xs:key>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="Position">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Latitude" type="xs:decimal"/>
        <xs:element name="Longitude" type="xs:decimal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Address">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="StreetNo">
            <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="[0-9]+"/>
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="StrName" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="City"   type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="State">
            <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{2}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="Zip">
            <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{5}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

buildings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<buildings>

<building>
    <BuildingCode>KOH</BuildingCode>
    <BuildingName>King Olympic Hall</BuildingName>
    <Position>
        <Latitude>34.024547</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-118.288</Longitude>
    </Position>
    <Address>
        <StreetNo>1027</StreetNo>
        <StrName>W 34th St</StrName>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90007</Zip>
    </Address>
</building>

<building>
    <BuildingCode>CFX</BuildingCode>
    <BuildingName>Cromwell Field</BuildingName>
    <Position>
        <Latitude>34.021631</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-118.289</Longitude>
    </Position>
    <Address>
        <StreetNo>1026</StreetNo>
        <StrName>W 34th St</StrName>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90089</Zip>
    </Address>
</building>

<building>
    <BuildingCode>JEP</BuildingCode>
    <BuildingName>JEP House</BuildingName>
    <Position>
        <Latitude>34.022947</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-118.284</Longitude>
    </Position>
    <Address>
        <StreetNo>801</StreetNo>
        <StrName>W 34th St</StrName>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90089</Zip>
    </Address>
</building>

<building>
    <BuildingCode>SHC</BuildingCode>
    <BuildingName>Student Health Center</BuildingName>
    <Position>
        <Latitude>34.023303</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-118.285</Longitude>
    </Position>
    <Address>
        <StreetNo>849</StreetNo>
        <StrName>W 34th St</StrName>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90089</Zip>
    </Address>
</building>

<building>
    <BuildingCode>LVY</BuildingCode>
    <BuildingName>Leavey Library</BuildingName>
    <Position>
        <Latitude>34.021595</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-118.282</Longitude>
    </Position>
    <Address>
        <StreetNo>651</StreetNo>
        <StrName>W 35th St</StrName>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90089</Zip>
    </Address>
</building>

<building>
    <BuildingCode>VKC</BuildingCode>
    <BuildingName>Von KleinSmid Center</BuildingName>
    <Position>
        <Latitude>34.021649</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-118.284</Longitude>
    </Position>
    <Address>
        <StreetNo>3518</StreetNo>
        <StrName>Trousdale</StrName>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90089</Zip>
    </Address>
</building>

<building>
    <BuildingCode>WPH</BuildingCode>
    <BuildingName>Waite Phillips Hall</BuildingName>
    <Position>
        <Latitude>34.022289</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-118.284</Longitude>
    </Position>
    <Address>
        <StreetNo>3550</StreetNo>
        <StrName>Trousdale</StrName>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90089</Zip>
    </Address>
</building>

<building>
    <BuildingCode>JHH</BuildingCode>
    <BuildingName>John Hubbard Hall</BuildingName>
    <Position>
        <Latitude>34.020101</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-118.284</Longitude>
    </Position>
    <Address>
        <StreetNo>615</StreetNo>
        <StrName>ChildsWay</StrName>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90089</Zip>
    </Address>
</building>

<building>
    <BuildingCode>REG</BuildingCode>
    <BuildingName>Registration Builing</BuildingName>
    <Position>
        <Latitude>34.019603</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-118.282</Longitude>
    </Position>
    <Address>
        <StreetNo>611</StreetNo>
        <StrName>ChildsWay</StrName>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90089</Zip>
    </Address>
</building>

<building>
    <BuildingCode>STU</BuildingCode>
    <BuildingName>Student Union</BuildingName>
    <Position>
        <Latitude>34.020226</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-118.286</Longitude>
    </Position>
    <Address>
        <StreetNo>3551</StreetNo>
        <StrName>Trousdale</StrName>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90089</Zip>
    </Address>
</building>

<building>
    <BuildingCode>BKS</BuildingCode>
    <BuildingName>Bookstore</BuildingName>
    <Position>
        <Latitude>34.020635</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-118.286</Longitude>
    </Position>
    <Address>
        <StreetNo>840</StreetNo>
        <StrName>ChildsWay</StrName>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90089</Zip>
    </Address>
</building>

<building>
    <BuildingCode>RTH</BuildingCode>
    <BuildingName>Ronald Tutor Hall</BuildingName>
    <Position>
        <Latitude>34.020137</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-118.29</Longitude>
    </Position>
    <Address>
        <StreetNo>3710</StreetNo>
        <StrName>McClintock</StrName>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90089</Zip>
    </Address>
</building>

<building>
    <BuildingCode>SAL</BuildingCode>
    <BuildingName>Salvatori Com. Center</BuildingName>
    <Position>
        <Latitude>34.01955</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-118.289</Longitude>
    </Position>
    <Address>
        <StreetNo>941</StreetNo>
        <StrName>W 37th Place</StrName>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90089</Zip>
    </Address>
</building>

<building>
    <BuildingCode>EEB</BuildingCode>
    <BuildingName>Electrical Engr Center</BuildingName>
    <Position>
        <Latitude>34.019728</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-118.29</Longitude>
    </Position>
    <Address>
        <StreetNo>3715</StreetNo>
        <StrName>McClintock</StrName>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90089</Zip>
    </Address>
</building>

<building>
    <BuildingCode>OHE</BuildingCode>
    <BuildingName>Olin Hall Engineering</BuildingName>
    <Position>
        <Latitude>34.020493</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-118.29</Longitude>
    </Position>
    <Address>
        <StreetNo>3650</StreetNo>
        <StrName>McClintock</StrName>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90089</Zip>
    </Address>
</building>
</buildings>
```

I want to set the BuildingCode as primary key and validate the buildings.xml file.I added a key named PKBuildingCode but it is not validating the xml file even if add duplicate BuildingCode in the xml file.
Can someone help me in solving the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just want `xsd:unique`:

```
<xs:unique name="PKBuildingCode">
    <xs:selector xpath="building"/>
    <xs:field xpath="BuildingCode"/>
</xs:unique>
```

See also:

> [Difference between xsd:key and xsd:unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253609/difference-between-xsdkey-and-xsdunique)

Comment: But I want to reference this element BuildingCode in another xsd file as foreign key.How can I do it?

Comment: You did not mention this in your question, did you? This is not possble, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914438/key-keyref-in-different-xsd-documents