# XSD - Make element set unique

Tags: xml, xsd, key

I have a set of elements, which altogether should be unique and i do not know how
to get this validated in my xsd.

```
<xs:element name="PLUGIN_PRIMAR_KEY">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="IID_INTERFACE_ID">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="DATA1"/>
                    <xs:element name="DATA2"/>
                    <xs:element name="DATA3"/>
                    <xs:element name="DATA4">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="BYTE0"/>
                                <xs:element name="BYTE1"/>
                                <xs:element name="BYTE2"/>
                                <xs:element name="BYTE3"/>
                                <xs:element name="BYTE4"/>
                                <xs:element name="BYTE5"/>
                                <xs:element name="BYTE6"/>
                                <xs:element name="BYTE7"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>   
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="UI64_VERSION"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

For example all elements in "IID_INTERFACE_ID" could be the same,
but if the "UI64_VERSION" element is not the same, it should be considered valid.

The example below is invalid, because all inner elements of two different `<PLUGIN_PRIMAR_KEY>` have the same values:

```
<PLUGIN_PRIMAR_KEY>
  <IID_INTERFACE_ID>
    <DATA1>29e4223c</DATA1>
    <DATA2>2d64</DATA2>
    <DATA3>45b4</DATA3>
    <DATA4>
      <BYTE0>94</BYTE0>
      <BYTE1>d9</BYTE1>
      <BYTE2>bd</BYTE2>
      <BYTE3>fa</BYTE3>
      <BYTE4>fd</BYTE4>
      <BYTE5>e3</BYTE5>
      <BYTE6>b1</BYTE6>
      <BYTE7>07</BYTE7>
    </DATA4>
  </IID_INTERFACE_ID>
  <UI64_VERSION>0000000000000000</UI64_VERSION>
</PLUGIN_PRIMAR_KEY>
<PLUGIN_PRIMAR_KEY>
  <IID_INTERFACE_ID>
    <DATA1>29e4223c</DATA1>
    <DATA2>2d64</DATA2>
    <DATA3>45b4</DATA3>
    <DATA4>
      <BYTE0>94</BYTE0>
      <BYTE1>d9</BYTE1>
      <BYTE2>bd</BYTE2>
      <BYTE3>fa</BYTE3>
      <BYTE4>fd</BYTE4>
      <BYTE5>e3</BYTE5>
      <BYTE6>b1</BYTE6>
      <BYTE7>07</BYTE7>
    </DATA4>
  </IID_INTERFACE_ID>
  <UI64_VERSION>0000000000000000</UI64_VERSION>
</PLUGIN_PRIMAR_KEY>
```

But if at least one element has different value, it will be valid:

```
<PLUGIN_PRIMAR_KEY>
  <IID_INTERFACE_ID>
    <DATA1>29e4223c</DATA1>
    <DATA2>2d64</DATA2>
    <DATA3>45b4</DATA3>
    <DATA4>
      <BYTE0>94</BYTE0>
      <BYTE1>d9</BYTE1>
      <BYTE2>bd</BYTE2>
      <BYTE3>fa</BYTE3>
      <BYTE4>fd</BYTE4>
      <BYTE5>e3</BYTE5>
      <BYTE6>b1</BYTE6>
      <BYTE7>07</BYTE7>
    </DATA4>
  </IID_INTERFACE_ID>
  <UI64_VERSION>0000000000000000</UI64_VERSION>
</PLUGIN_PRIMAR_KEY>
<PLUGIN_PRIMAR_KEY>
  <IID_INTERFACE_ID>
    <DATA1>29e4223c</DATA1>
    <DATA2>2d64</DATA2>
    <DATA3>45b4</DATA3>
    <DATA4>
      <BYTE0>94</BYTE0>
      <BYTE1>d9</BYTE1>
      <BYTE2>bd</BYTE2>
      <BYTE3>fa</BYTE3>
      <BYTE4>fd</BYTE4>
      <BYTE5>e3</BYTE5>
      <BYTE6>b1</BYTE6>
      <BYTE7>07</BYTE7>
    </DATA4>
  </IID_INTERFACE_ID>
  <UI64_VERSION>0000000000000001</UI64_VERSION>
</PLUGIN_PRIMAR_KEY>
```

The PLUGIN_PRIMAR_KEY element is embedded in some ohter element which contains one dataset.

Thanks for help in advance,
TinTin

Comment: Can you give some examples of both valid and invalid xmls? It's not very clear what exactly you need.

Comment: Can you look if this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926876/how-to-define-xml-primary-key-in-xsd-file-and-validate-in-xml-file